# When are we getting the new user pages?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page

Stack Exchange just debuted [new user profile pages](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/04/two-new-user-pages-one-new-stat-this-ones-big/?cb=1), and they're pretty great.

Are they coming to RPG.se?  When?

Answer (score 9):

They are coming to all of SE, including RPG.se.

These updates depend on [the rollout of a new CSS framework](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed). We are apparently set up with that new framework (as evidenced by a recent bug in it that showed up here briefly), so it's just a matter of time before we also get the new pages code rollout.

(I'm anxious for them too! They are pretty great.)

As of November 2015, [they are imminent](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5912/a-design-update-is-coming)!

Comment: With that said, [this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253359/276044) suggests that we don't have the updates yet, so it's a bit odd.

Comment: @Miniman It looks like they're not updating that in realtime. If I was doing a new code rollout, I wouldn't spend time updating it either. :)

Comment: @Miniman It is probably out of date. We just yesterday experienced the same CSS bug that Stack Overflow (which _is_ set up with the updates) experienced.

Comment: Hey, I just thought I'd mention it :P

Comment: @Miniman If I had to guess, they could roll out a stack of sites at once, since they share relevant design patterns. However, graduated sites probably need to be vetted manually. Just a guess, though.

Comment: @Emrakul I think it's also a way to catch more bugs. Deploy in expanding waves, and lots of things can be caught earlier than otherwise.