# Questions with favorite tags are not being highlighted

Tags: bug, status-completed, css, site-design

Cross-posting from [Updates to the site](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5920/4563), since it was a bug with that update that appears to have gotten missed. Comments on that answer haven’t seemed to get noticed, so giving this a little more visibility:

> Questions with favorited tags are no longer being highlighted.
>
> [image]
>
> It's difficult to get a good screenshot of this, but it's easy to check.

I’m still seeing this, and based on the four upvotes on my comment to that effect, so are others. This is despite the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) entry on the answer, suggesting that it would be live after the next build (all other fixes marked the same have been visible for several days).

Comment: +1 still seeing it also

Comment: Would love to hear back about this, anyway we can bring this to their attention further?

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith No idea.

Comment: I have also noticed this.

Comment: This bug is back today.

Comment: This is still occurring as of January 15th.

Comment: Still seeing it.  It's the reason I haven't really been engaging lately. :(

Comment: Would it be right to edit or flag the corresponding answer in the "Updates to the site" question? I mean, the answer does make a false claim (it should not be "status-completed"), but simply voting it down as we would a normal non-meta answer doesn't really do much in this format. It might bring more attention to the issue.

Comment: This is still broken...

Comment: I'm very happy to be able to put a [status-completed] on this as of April 1st. *We have our highlights back!*