# Winter is Coming… to bring us hats!

Tags: discussion, winterbash, hats, winterbash-2015

It's rainy where I am because Wet Coast, but it will soon be snowing at [winterbash2015.stackexchange.com](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/). And just like last year, there will be ***hats***.

## Hats

### Hats

#### Hats

**Hats**

So many hats.

(Also, check out that sweet set of [differentiated and well-spaced](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5923/321) headers and bold text!)

## “Wait, *hats*? What are you gibbering about.”

Winterbash is a yearly Stack Exchange tradition in which actions on the site unlock [virtual hats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244075/what-is-a-hat) for your avatar to wear. (Last year size and angle customisation was added, so most hats can be made to fit most avatars, even weird ones like, I don't know, awkwardly-angled dice.) They're like badges, but for smaller or sillier actions and much more temporary — the hats go back in their boxes on January 4th.

The [Winterbash site](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/) lists the hats you have earned as well as those yet to be earned, with hints on how to earn them, as well as site and cross-network leaderboards so you can indulge the natural competitive millinery urges we all have but never admit to in polite company.

As they are every year, this year's hats are all-new. There are also secret hats, which will take some luck or skill to earn. But don't tell anyone I told you.

And just like in previous years, hats with have an opt-out option in your profile, so if you don't want to see hats, you can banish all hats from your sight so they may not offend thine eye.

**Winterbash 2015 begins December 14th. Prepare for dapperness!**

Comment: HATS 4 DAYZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith [DayZ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DayZ_%28mod%29) is getting hats?!

Comment: *pops head in. Hats for daze!

Comment: I notice the little stick people making up the countdown for Winterbash don't have any hats! How terrible. No wonder they're so eager for Winterbash as to be counting down for it.

Comment: @doppelgreener The first time each hat is earned, a little stick person will be be-hatted.  When every hat is earned, every stick person will have a hat.  Obsvly.

Comment: "...even weird ones like, I don't know, awkwardly-angled dice." I second the motion to have a seven-sided die "hat"

Comment: related: [2015 hatmas album](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5964/23970)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

THE HATTENING, IT BEGINS.

[image]