# Hatocalypse 2016 Survivors' Photo Album

Tags: discussion, winterbash, winterbash-2016

> This album is for **2016**. Check out the 2017 album here: [The Hatmas Interdimensional Breach 2017 Photo Album](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7622/the-hatmas-interdimensional-breach-2017-photo-album)

[As prophecy foretold](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6615/1204), the Hatocalypse is upon us. Some of us may survive. Some may only be uncovered later under the debris of so many hats; rest assured our thoughts will be with you. Some of us have this cozy vault to enjoy, sealing us off from the millinery hazards outside.

Let's not let the dreaded hatocalypse keep us down though: let's keep another [fun and silly yearbook](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5964/the-winterbash-hatmas-photo-album-maybe-embarrassing-yearbook) of the events (and hats) that unfold, for those of us who survive the wave of hats to look back upon and enjoy in the future.

Keep it fun and [be nice](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). (Everyone's going to feel self conscious posting anything here, so I suggest we leave criticism at the door.) Go for one post per person, or a very small number.

---

For those not in the super secret partial screenshot skills club, here's how you do it. First, [here's a magic link to your public profile](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) that's perfect for screenshotting. Now, the method:

- On Windows 7 and above, you can use the built-in [Snipping Tool](https://superuser.com/a/404279/50208) on your profile page (just hit start and type in the name). Otherwise, you may want to just take a screenshot of your browser window with alt+print screen, paste it into MS Paint, crop out your avatar region and save it as a **PNG**. (GIFs and JPGs will probably come out low quality.)
- On Mac, press CMD + SHIFT + 4 and then click and drag to outline your icon. When you let go of the mouse, it'll save a screenshot .png of the selection to your desktop.
- On Linux... I also have no idea, someone edit this in!

---

You can check the [leaderboards](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/rpg.stackexchange.com) to see who has been cursed with the largest number of hats.

Comment: Folks want to know: Is it [*hatocalypse*](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6640/8610) or [*hatpocalypse*](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6615/8610)? (*Note: Folks*, in this case, is me.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan The ongoing hatnarok is no time for standardisation! It's the hatmageddon! There's hataclysmic devhatstation everywhere! Get under shelter! (For a serious answer I didn't even notice the difference and now I'm tempted to suggest we call it all kinds of things. :D)

Comment: ***The Hataclysm.*** That's a keeper.

Comment: I do like Hatcalysm for some reason, though most of them are pretty good, I also like Hatnarok

Comment: ***Hatnarok*** gets my vote--good call by troggy. (And he knows about bringing death and destruction!)

Comment: It seems specious to ask an *actual* meta question about hats, so I, instead, pose it here: are the guidelines for earning or receiving secrets hats ever revealed?

Comment: @HeyICanChan The exact circumstances are typically revealed after Winterbash by the staff. The community will usually guess most of them in the All Hats question.

Comment: Kudos to whoever plopped a hat on [Community](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community).

Comment: @HeyICanChan specifically, here's the [all hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288271/311001) meta.SE question greener references, in case you haven't seen it. It's also got links to a chat room for conspiracy theorhaticians and a GDoc with persistent test-notes. I suggest grabbing "What's up, Doc?" before falling down *that* particular hole =)

Answer (score 28):

[image: Sheep Vader]
[image: Abominable Sheep]
[image: Sheep Phone]
[image: Bunny Sheep]
[image: Trophy Sheep]
[image: Rainbow vomit sheep]
[image: Grinch Sheep]
[image: Taco Sheep]
[image: Took Sheep]
[image: Spork Sheep]
[image: Deerstalker Sheep]
[image: Sheep Falkor]
[image: Sheeparound]
[image: Goldmoon]
[image: Waffle Sheep]
[image: Yoda Sheep]
[image: Ernie Sheep]
[image: This Sheep's on Fire!]
[image: Blue-footed sheep]
[image: Bert Sheep]
[image: golden sheep]
[image: dreidel sheep]
[image: noel sheep]
[image: trendsetting sheep]
[image: bacon sheep]
[image: irish sheep]
[image: sheep hatter]
[image: selfie sheep]
[image: sheep alex]
[image: angora sheep]

Comment: [mashes upvote button harder]

Comment: @BESW aww... I'm blushing. And vomiting. Rainbows and sparkles.

Comment: cute!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 14):

### The March of Dark Fathers

Last year I [put doctors in the Fourth Doctor's hat and scarf](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5965/4398). This year, every day a famously awful father gets to wear Darth Vader's mask. Hover over an image to see the bad dad's name and origin; click to see him unmasked.

[image: Jack Torrance (The Shining)] [image: Robert Ford (Westworld)] [image: Trigon the Terrible (Teen Titans Go!)] [image: Dr. Evil (Austin Powers)] [image: Immortan Joe (Mad Max: Fury Road)] [image: Marty (Steven Universe)] [image: System Lord Apophis (Stargate: SG-1)] [image: King Henry VIII (British history)] [image: Ming the Merciless (Flash Gordon)] [image: Fire Lord Ozai (Avatar: the Last Airbender)] [image: Shou Tucker (Full Metal Alchemist)] [image: Anakin Skywalker (Star Wars)] [image: Leland Palmer (Twin Peaks)] [image: Thanos (Marvel Comics)] [image: Howard Stark (Marvel Cinematic Universe)] [image: The Dark Savant (Wizardry, the Dark Savant trilogy)] [image: King Laius (Oedipus Rex)] [image: Hunson Abadeer (Adventure Time)] [image: Gehn (Riven)] [image: Denethor II (The Lord of the Rings)]

And please, drop by [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) with suggestions for bad dads!

Answer (score 12):

Hats often don't fit my avatar, so the few that do look good are always a treat. This is my favourite:

[image: Where in the World? hat]

And this one somehow catches my fancy too:

[image: Cutting the Cord hat]

Some more whimsical hattery:

[image: Bûche de Noël hat]
[image: Like Clockwork hat]
[image: Elementary hat]
[image: I Have A Little Dreidel hat]

(I admit that these latter hats are not *quite* fitted to the angles of my pentagonal prism because I don't want to mess with the positioning, so I can switch back to the Where in the World? hat exactly as it was. It's really grown on me. Some do sit nicely on the **7** itself though.)

Comment: this is my favorite, just the best. that symmetry really pulls it off

Comment: I really miss my sun hat…

Comment: you could get it back if you wanted to rip the picture of it on your avatar and use that :) it's what I did with my moon picture, I just loved it to much to let it go away when the hats were gone XD

Comment: @trogdor Sadly, it is bigger than the image frame! Especially including the sparkles. It would be a very tiny facsimile. :(

Comment: aw dang, if you had resolved to do it before it was gone, it would have worked :(

Comment: @trogdor I actually saved the raw SVG data for posterity, so I *could* still recombine them manually. It would just make the resulting avatar taller than the existing avatar, and the site would shrink it to fit inside the image frame everywhere on the site.

Comment: ah, I just used the snip tool thing just like how I make posts on these hat threads, so I have all the hats I put in here saved. not that I really intend to use any other than the moon one, cause it is just my favorite

Answer (score 11):

[image: Abominable hat]I [has been found](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/1f/9f/f9/1f9ff9cebc79d7c68c69d2ac7ee61511.jpg)!

[image: I Am Your Father hat]I can has [moar cats](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/48/01/6d/48016d154cf3ba949698c8f4d33728ee.jpg)?

[image: Cutting the Cord hat]Could you guys [keep it down](http://www.imgderp.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/41/2012/09/cat-on-the-phone.jpg)? I'm trying to order a cheeseburger.

[image: Where in the World hat here] Now I just need a [magical girl](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/dd/e5/7f/dde57fd1d198ffcf2a05eff7c23f0cc2.jpg)...

[image] [Grumpy, I am.](https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/1019863/screenshots/2417255/yoda_the_cat.jpg)

Comment: You look so happy as an abominable snowman!

Comment: Lunasage and Phonesage are excellent.

Answer (score 11):

Doot and snoot

[image: Doot][image: snoot]

Perhaps I will find a fancier hat for my greyhound soon

Answer (score 9):

[image][image]

this hat is the first secret hat I remember getting any Winterbash, seems like it works for this picture to me

[image]

[image]

ok, I kinda had to add these two when I saw how they looked XD ( I lied, there are 3 now)

Answer (score 7):

I'm ready for my close-up…

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Most times I feel like a dude (left), but other times I feel like a sweet lass (right). Either way, I'm really feeling the winter cheer.

[image: Dapper duder pon.] [image: Pictured: The sweetest lass, who still doesn't see the point of all this.]

Answer (score 3):

Much to the surprise of people who know me, I have been ruled not a grinch.

[image]  [image][image]

The caption for the second one is: *I find your lack of sources disturbing, commander.* The third one looks like a spork.