# The Hatmas Interdimensional Breach 2017 Photo Album

Tags: discussion, winterbash

> This album is for **2017**. Check out the 2018 album here: [The Large Hatron Collider Experimental Hatastrophe 2018: Winterbash Photo Album](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8617/1204)

It's that time of year we fear every year: the interdimensional barriers between the dimension of hats and our own has broken down to critical and inevitable degrees. The rifts are open. The hats are upon us, here to consume us and preoccupy us like so many intellect devourers and to compel us to celebrate this horrific reality breakdown cascade. So without further ado...

***Hooraaaayy! Hatmas time!***

This only happens once a year for a few weeks, and then the hats go away again and the dimensional breaches close, hopefully forever and ever. But the memories don't have to! We can take photos and keep those! And study them later when our free will returns to us, to better identify ways to defend our noggins from these creatures! Thus: **a photo album!**

## The album!

Take screenshots of fun or memorable hats you've worn or seen others wear, and share them here. Go for one post each (with any number of photos therein) or a very small number.

Keep it fun and [be nice](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). Everyone's going to feel self conscious posting anything here, so I suggest we leave criticism at the door.

## How do I take screenshots?

- **Lightshot** is a popular simple screenshot extension [for **Firefox**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lightshot/) or [for **Chrome**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lightshot-screenshot-tool/mbniclmhobmnbdlbpiphghaielnnpgdp?hl=en) that will let you screenshot just a small portion of the page.
- **Windows 7 and above:** Use the built-in [Snipping Tool](https://superuser.com/a/404279/50208); just hit start and type in the name. Otherwise you can take a screenshot of your browser window with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>print screen</kbd>, paste it into MS Paint, crop it down to just the avatar, and save it as a **PNG**. (GIFs and JPGs will probably come out low quality.)
- **Mac:** press <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>, then click and drag to outline the space you want to screenshot. When you let go of the mouse, it'll save a screenshot .png of the selection to your desktop.
- **On Linux:** Gnome/Ubuntu: press <kbd>shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>print screen</kbd>, then click-and-drag over the area on the screen you want to screenshot. A prompt window will appear giving you a choice to save or copy the image to clipboard. If the shortcut doesn't work, either set it up in System Settings/Keyboard/shortcurts/screenshots or use a tool like [Shutter](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/shutter).

[Here's a magic link to your public profile](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) that's perfect for screenshots.

---

You can check the [leaderboards](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/rpg.stackexchange.com) to see who has been victim to the largest number of hats attempting to gnaw at their head.

Comment: Should this get featured? I was kind of disappointed to not see anything site-specific about Winter Bash on the right there (didn’t think to check meta directly).

Comment: @KRyan Good thinking! It's featured now :)

Comment: "Leaderboards" link appears to point to 2016 hat page, but the [promos page](http://stackpromos.com/promos) doesn't seem to have a 2017 version...is this year's page not up yet?

Comment: @A_S00 Whoops, thanks! Link updated.

Answer (score 14):

### Detectives: The Deerstalkerening

In 2015 I [put doctors in the Fourth Doctor's hat and scarf](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5965/4398). In 2016, [famously awful fathers got to wear Darth Vader's mask](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6644/4398). This year detectives will take turns trying on Sherlock Holmes's iconic deerstalker and using his magnifying glass. Hover over an image to see the detective's name and origin; click to see them unhatted.

[image: Leroy Brown ('Encyclopedia Brown' novels by Donald J Sobol)]
[image: Police Constable Peter Grant ('Rivers of London' novels by Ben Aaronovitch)]
[image: Goldie Vance ('Goldie Vance' comic by Hope Larson, Brittney Williams)]
[image: Victoria 'Vikki' Allen (Nan-Lynn Nelson in 'The Bloodhound Gang' on 3-2-1 Contact TV show)]
[image: Detective Dee (Andy Lau in 'Detective Dee and the Mystery of the Phantom Flame' film)]
[image: Ezekiel "Easy" Porterhouse Rawlins (Denzel Washington in 'Devil with a Blue Dress' film based on Walter Mosley's book of the same name)]
[image: Maddy Magellan (Caroline Quentin in 'Jonathan Creek' TV show)]
[image: Justice Bao Zheng (11 April 999 – 20 May 1062, statue in Xiqing Park)]
[image: Brülightly ('Britten and Brülightly' comic by Hannah Berry)]
[image: SO-27 Detective Thursday Next ('Thursday Next' novels by Jasper Fforde)]
[image: Detective Virgil Tibbs (Sidney Poitier in film 'In the Heat of the Night' based on John Ball's novel of the same name)]
[image: Gwen Dylan, née Gwendolyn Price ('iZOMBIE' comic by Chris Roberson & Michael Allred)]
[image: Albert Campion (Peter Davison in 1989 TV series 'Campion' based on Margery Allingham's novels)]
[image: Nate the Great ('Nate the Great' novels by Marjorie Weinman Sharmat, illustration by Marc Simont)]
[image: Erast Petrovich Fandorin ('Fandorin' novels by Boris Akunin)]
[image: Lovejoy (Ian McShane in 'Lovejoy' TV series inspired by Jonathan Gash's novels)]
[image: Osmosis "Ozzy" Jones ('Osmosis Jones' film)]
[image: Doctor Joan Watson (Lucy Liu in TV series 'Elementary')]
[image: Carl Kolchak (Darren McGavin in TV series 'Kolchak: The Night Stalker')]
[image: Agent Cleopatra Jones (Tamara Dobson in film 'Cleopatra Jones')]
[image: James Ellison (Richard T. Jones in TV series 'Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles')]

And please, drop by [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) with suggestions for hatworthy detectives!

Answer (score 13):

[image: Bespectacled octopus with Oprah Stache!]

I thought to go easy this year,
as most hats cover my glasses,
but what's more joyous and festive
than molluscs wearing moustaches?

Comment: I read this as sung by Dean Martin to the tune of Let It Snow. ([yt link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mN7LW0Y00kE))

Comment: I read this in my in brain narration voice, and it turned into my in brain singing voice (or maybe he is my in brain poets voice?) XD

Answer (score 12):

[Community](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) has a hat!

[image: van hellsing hat and crossbow at a jaunty angle]

Comment: Community's hat changes occasionally; if you spot them wearing another hat feel free to snap a pic and post it here =)

Comment: I really love this hat on Community,.... does it change it's own hat or does  someone decide "hey I would like it to wear this one now"?

Comment: @trogdor My running theory is that Santa does it.

Answer (score 10):

Last year, I didn't get into the hat craze, this year I'm making up for it!

Here's a dog cosplaying a dog while playing DnD while his beverage and PHB is on fire, he looks just a bit dismayed, if I'm honest:
[image]

Comment: This dog is amazing. And horrifying. I love it.

Comment: this is my favorite one right now

Answer (score 8):

[image] 
[image: bow]
[image: mario hat]

I did some Green Diamond hats, then decided... someone else would wear them better.

PERIDOT DOES! So I'm going to celebrate Peridot with a Peridot of hats. (That's a collective noun now.)

[image: peridot with a mario hat]
[image: ginormous rep cap]
[image: santa hat]
[image: peridot with a top hat and monocle and fine moustache, licking a rock]
[image: yellow diamond with a mod hat]
[image: jester hat]
[image: mad hatter]
[image: 2018 glasses]
[image: ze goggles]

Comment: @trogdor I'm loving it too. I can't wait to do more of these. :D

Comment: [mashes upvote button harder]

Answer (score 7):

This year I've made a "no hat-chasing" resolution--we'll see how it goes!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: the no hat resolution seems to be going very well :P

Comment: It's working out well for @Miniman =D

Answer (score 4):

Last year I had a nice white hat.

[image]

This year I've turned to the dark side, with this secret hat.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

During Hatmastide, the Stack and Chat has been visited upon by Sagely Otters on their quest for joy and discovery. But heavens, upon closer inspection, what do we notice? There is only one Sagely Otter, and the very convincing change in appearance is due to naught but change of headgear! So verily, the Forest Gnome Otter (Top Left), the Fashiotter (Top Right) and the Casual Casual Otter (Bottom Left) are all the same Sagely Otter!

[image: Hatmas photos of otter in blankets]

Also included for reference a Sagely Narwhalrus (Bottom Right).

Answer (score 2):

[image: head volleyball, also two silly hats in one picture]

here we go, this is the complete post, both hats on two different heads, I may or may not bother with any others

[image]

I accidentally done get secret hat? I figured I would give it a shot on here

[image]

ok, so this one is two other new hats, I figured they went well together (I dunno, like an eyepiece looking at a sun thingy, wtv right?)

Comment: also, the image gets too small if I try to use both hats on my actual avatar, so I will be more than content with just the unicorn hat thing with that