# The Large Hatron Collider Woolly Hatastrophe 2018: Winterbash Photo Album

Tags: discussion, winterbash

The physicists have done it again! They know no limits in meddling with the fabric of reality, and now the large hatron collider has exploded and there's hats and wool everywhere. How irresponsible!

Well, let's take some photos and do some knitting while we're here.

---

Every Hatmas, we wear and see fun and dapper combinations of hats: the hats go away at the end of the Hatmas season, but we can still preserve some memories and pictures of the fabulous hattery we've seen. To that end:

**Let's have a fun and/or slightly embarrassing yearbook.** Post the great hats and hatments you've seen. Show off the ones *you* made for yourself which you think are fantastic or fabulous or the greatest. If you spy an excellent thing in the wild, I guess you can stick that here too.

This year also has a wool theme (head to [the Winterbash 2018 page](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/) and hit “Start Knitting”!), and your woolly works of woven art are more than welcome here too. (There is also [a Winter Bash 2018 Knitting gallery on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319846/152515).)

I recommend one answer per person (or a small number), and revise it to make additions. Keep it silly, keep it fun, and [be nice](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). (Everyone's going to feel self conscious posting anything here, so I suggest we leave criticism at the door.)

---

### How do I take a screenshot?

- Use the **Lightshot** extension [for **Firefox**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lightshot/) or [for **Chrome**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lightshot-screenshot-tool/mbniclmhobmnbdlbpiphghaielnnpgdp?hl=en).
- **Windows 7 and above:** Use the built-in [Snipping Tool](https://superuser.com/a/404279/50208) (hit start, type its name). Otherwise take a screenshot of your browser with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>print screen</kbd>, crop it in MS Paint, and save it as a PNG (not GIF or JPEG).
- **Mac:** press <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>, then click and drag to outline the region you want to screenshot. The screenshot will be saved to your desktop.
- **On Linux:** Gnome/Ubuntu: press <kbd>shift ⇧</kbd> + <kbd>print screen</kbd>, then click-and-drag over the region you want to screenshot and save the screenshot somewhere. If the shortcut doesn't work, either set it up in System Settings/Keyboard/shortcuts/screenshots or use a tool like [Shutter](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/shutter).

[Here's a magic link to your public profile](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) that's perfect for screenshots.

Comment: A useful resource for finding hotkeys for taking screenshots on every major desktop or mobile OS: https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Answer (score 10):

Junimo!

[image: bring me upvotes!]

And I'd submitted this over on the main meta:

[image: D&D_logo]

Answer (score 10):

### Retro Fan: Originals

In 2015 I [put doctors in the Fourth Doctor's hat and scarf](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5965/4398). In 2016, [famously awful fathers got to wear Darth Vader's mask](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6644/4398). In 2017 [detectives wore Sherlock Holmes's hat](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7624/4398).

This year I'll be putting the Retro Fan glasses on original versions of characters with multiple iterations. Hover over an image to see the character's name and origin; click to see them unhatted.

[image: Edward Bear, the original Winnie-the-Pooh]
[image: Ged, AKA Sparrowhawk, from the first edition over of 'A Wizard of Earthsea']
[image: Godzilla, from a poster for the 1954 film]
[image: Jaime Reyes, Marvel Comics (pre-New-52)]
[image: Kermit the Frog (Smithsonian display)]

Comment: Heck yeah, king lizard

Comment: @Tiggerous ...yes. Jaime always twigs Marvel-side for me, because he passes the "street ID defines hero ID" test.

Answer (score 9):

### No hats yet, but I'm [knitting](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/) to stay warm....

[image]

Comment: Just don't let the other sheep see it

Answer (score 9):

Since Trogdor is lazy and didn't repost herethe image I left from him in chat, I suppose I have to do it.

[image: Beholder]

Comment: Lol, you did ask me to do my own beholder, why should I waste perfectly good derpy art I made myself :P

Comment: I just said you should have posted that here for historical record :P Didn't expect you to switch at all, @trogdor. The Derpholder is a perfect avatar for this season

Comment: fair enough, I misunderstood you then, but maybe it's better you got to post this

Answer (score 8):

Have you ever wondered what happens when you dunk your headgear into your coffee?

[image: Retro Fan]
[image: Still Fresh]
[image: Team Player]
[image: Top Bar]
[image: Identification Division]
[image: Red Baron]
[image: Scarf Ace]

Comment: Now those will be some tough stains to get out.

Comment: Mmm candy sunglasses in coffee, XD

Comment: Nice cropping skills... ;-)

Answer (score 7):

## Knitting with hooves is hard!

[image]

Comment: somehow, this looks actually knitted.

Answer (score 7):

My first hat, and it's a green one!

[image: Queen Chrysalis in a green bamboo box hat]

Or, wait... I saw someone wearing it upside down before... could it be..!?

[image: Queen Chrysalis's head sticking out of the box like a jack-in-the-box]

Time to switch back to an oldie but a goodie for some of the holidays; if anyone's going to wear Retro Fan it's gotta be Space Ghost:

[image: Space Ghost in retro fan glasses (shutter shades)]
[image: Space Ghost in a robotcop helmet]

Comment: That second one is great, I didn't realize you could do that with this hat XD

Comment: yesss, almost as good as Zorak's indeed

Answer (score 6):

Gearing up for winter: it's snowing here in Chapel Hill, folks!

[image: Gearing up for the winter weather]

Just because I started with D&D 5e doesn't mean I can't be an old-school retro fan! (I use `vim` for just about everything, how much more retro can you get...)

[image: I can't see through these retro glasses]

**My players navigating the extreme wilderness...**

> *Rolls a 1*
>
> You hear the sounds of bones crunching and, as you approach, catch sight of an owlbear ravaging some goblin and merchant corpses, with a damaged caravan nearby. What do you do?

[image: Exploring unknown territory]

Answer (score 6):

Waffles anyone?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Sharing means Gimme!] I just couldn't resist a little break for this one

[image: the Hand,... the Foot,... the Apendage? is here]

this here is the goofholder without a hat

[image: Enough with the puns yet? Behold the goofholder]

[image: trying out for the NFL I guess?]

and here we have a be-hatted beholder

Comment: Zorak wears them better, as I thought! :D

Comment: Space Ghost still looks pretty good too, glad you thought of it and gave me this idea too XD

Answer (score 2):

[image]
*Caps for sale, fifty cents per cap.*

Comment: I love that book!

Comment: @NautArch So did my kids, and so did I when I was a kid.

Answer (score 2):

I forgot to post it during Winterbash, but Community had a hat too:

[image: Community bot user in a Robocop helmet]